# Select themes sticky expended header hide

Tags: html, css, wordpress, select, wordpress-theming

So on my wordpress page with the theme stockholm from select themes. I have an sticky expended header. I have it set so that it is only sticky after 100px scroll. Now that's fine, but the header is now standard on top of the page. I want to hide it. The problem is that if I hide it the sticky version also goes away. Any way of fixing this?

[image: This one needs to go away]

[image: This one needs to stay]

Comment: Hi can you give us link to the site ?

Comment: It's local at the moment but give me a couple of minutes :)

Comment: ok, so share the code of this elements :)

Comment: @ArturBrzozowski http://dev.itpixels.be here you can clearly see that the main navigation is (like standard) on top of the page. But I only want the sticky one after scroll to make it cleaner :)

Comment: This is not enough information for us to help. You need to show us the relevant code and tell us what you have tried already. Before posting, you are expected to have *researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself*, and this is in **your own interest** - we can't help you if we don't know how your site is set up, how the code is making the nav sticky and what you have already done yourself to fix it... we are not mind readers! You need to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have sticky menu all time you need to add

```
sticky sticky_animate //classes to header
```

so it would look like

```
<header class="page_header transparent scrolled_not_transparent light stick menu_bottom sticky sticky_animate">
```

and turn off your javascript